# Combining Typescript generics with any without losing type

Tags: typescript, strong-typing, nexus-prisma

This is related to a [plugin](https://github.com/Sytten/nexus-shield) I am building for the [@nexus/schema](https://github.com/graphql-nexus/schema) library (type-safe GraphQL), but it is purely a Typescript typing issue.

I have a rules system where all my rules are derived form this interface:

```js
interface Rule<Type extends string, Field extends string> {
  resolve(root: RootValue<Type>, args: ArgsValue<Type, Field>): boolean;
}
```

Note: The `RootValue` and `ArgsValue` are types used to fetch the "real" generated type or return `any`, this is a trick nexus uses to type everything without the use needing to explicitly specify the type.
[See this link for the source code](https://github.com/graphql-nexus/schema/blob/bf0df64ebd9810f9a458aceb8c5ff52518607825/src/typegenTypeHelpers.ts#L238).

The two most basic are:

```js
type Options = { cache?: boolean }

type RuleFunc<Type extends string, Field extends string> =
  (root: RootValue<Type>, args: ArgsValue<Type, Field>) => boolean;

class BaseRule<Type extends string, Field extends string> implements Rule<Type, Field> {
  constructor(private options: Options, private func: RuleFunc<Type, Field>) {}

  resolve(root: RootValue<Type>, args: ArgsValue<Type, Field>) {
    // Do stuff with the options
    const result = this.func(root, args)
    return result
  }
}

class AndRule<Type extends string, Field extends string> implements Rule<Type, Field> {
  constructor(private rules: Rule<Type, Field>[]) { }

  resolve(root: RootValue<Type>, args: ArgsValue<Type, Field>) {
    return this.rules
      .map(r => r.resolve(root, args))
      .reduce((acc, val) => acc && val)
  }
}
```

I then define helpers:

```js
const rule = (options?: Options) =>
  <Type extends string, Field extends string>(func: RuleFunc<Type, Field>): Rule<Type, Field> => {
    options = options || {};
    return new BaseRule<Type, Field>(options, func);
  };

const and = <Type extends string, Field extends string>(...rules: Rule<Type, Field>[]): Rule<Type, Field> => {
  return new AndRule(rules)
}
```

My problem is that I need to be able to support generic rules that apply to all types/fields and specific rules only for one type/field. But if I combine a generic rule with a specific rule, the resulting rule is a `Rule<any, any>` which then allows bad rules to be accepted.

```js
const genericRule = rule()<any, any>((root, args) => { return true; })

const myBadRule = rule()<"OtherType", "OtherField">((root, args) => {
  return true;
})

const myRule: Rule<"Test", "prop"> = and(
  rule()((root, args) => {
    return false
  }),
  genericRule,
  myBadRule // THIS SHOULD BE AN ERROR
)
```

I am guessing that has to do in part with the lack of existential typing in Typescript that basically forces me to use a `any` in the first place, but is there a workaround that I could use to prevent the type the `any` from overriding my type. One workaround I found is to explicitly type the `and`, but that is not nice from a usability perspective.

**EDIT 2:** I created a [playground with a simplified version so it easier to view the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEEkDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrAsAKGgTwA6ygDy+0AlgPaQDOoAvKAN6g0AWlArgDYAmAYsm41YALlAAjSpW6xkkUAF9s2cjAQp0oAEo9YAHgAqBWABpQ-crD4A+ZtlCh4sGjIBusABTxp0cccJzZHgAcxpxS2tec0oycJIyKloASnEpGTlIAG5sZSxsPEIdPX5OSFQjE3NI2wYHUG9ffyrQYLCIqz5khjt02Xkc-KwQYtkabFRuZBo6ACFp2F1ZSsCLTt47cgBbfFkt2Bg6JYMAszWouyZ61GoaaHhOVGhKeE98eHI3ZDhQRDLUcTHUrlFZnGobbpMPL1ZyubgeRqUPygU5BULxcExOLiUgUW6Q+qOciIBqxaA0AB07C4fEEwlg3Wc0E48AUKHphNA1hETlgzNZoGgbHIlL+5UR0DRYWS9Ty0Kwk2mdAAgpBeMdQdV1psdnsDuTRicWuDLtdbvdHs9Xu9Pt8iA8xoC9JrzrYANoAXUhShUWEcsPcXh8SOaqzaGPWWPJOMS+PsfscvP5CiFIopDpcnMcFK2yHw3h6TnTLkDEqlNCjNGSMoTidAxd4jy8njQqHMX243XodlboAAZH3QB2a445b6RgAJayEeDjBXmpx6BigF0mzxigGG4EVVGuiFO5a7k2Fq4JpkshSQWAAd1A8xEx3X-xr8putGgrTVy9X2s8FP-GbxBqR7ap6qSGj+FwnjCfIXqAV63qq6p6N4ehVrk45gAACj4Eh7L6b53KAIQHAg5CoMcy4Zvo8i4EEkC4DYnhlq06JdpcSZwRasBZEoNYTAuWy4PMyGyFRzoAETEEKCCnBJ5hSTJ8DghJTEseG7Hxv6sECtxgyKPxOAmKAACyuCnMuLCQMg+ziHcHyQCEPpGUUZngpZoDvLEaTSP0Ch5IRH5CccB4GGZu5udqy7yLwngwih6lsdBtacQK7IiLKySmPUJFXh8FF6NlCZCSJlEjIYE7gAAyqAVUTsQACqAAyAAid4AKKgMqAByoDtdo2jENo2A1kAA).

**EDIT 3:** As pointed out in the comments, `never` works with the previous example. [I thus created this example for which `never` does not work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=97&ssc=2&pln=85&pc=1#code/PTAEDkFMA8FcGdQAtIBsAOkBOiAuB7UAc0l2MgDtsBDXSAE1FwE9N4BYAKBc1AHFKAFVaR4AZSTVMAaUjNEAXlAAiLPny5hbZaAA+KgGYBLNPS2id+5dSxFz8ZQG4uPSPyEjxk3koBKkAGN8LHoAHgEKewkpSFl5ABpQagpmAD5nbhF3XAiAJlDpUBg6CnpECKjvWLl4ROlcougSstAAazl8A3dIz2jMAG1pAF1U0CUoOHgIxubEIwoDbG77UAB+Zc8ZyhaK3qq10ELi7cR25k6NtgP6rdLTjq7dtkGhg6fRF8Hc14AuJJTQH9ksxAf8QUCUhlXNkIgBmAq3HYeNh9aoJQ4NY53UAAUSaWGoAVwoTOF3eXhiL0S8FwWHmRFSdVhiMQeNphOJpMeyNEqM+9SG1Np9MZoAAYtRUKgAEaE1pjMGjcYwBDTLEteaLLCXURvHmIdXlfWo64stoPHWIdY3Q3m87cnrPYbXZm2rmW-nfPWOj7DL5DQaw37iyUyuWg4ERgEQ8FgqFZAAS1CmlHhRyaJ0tqLitQxZrZBKJJIt5L5wyFdIoDKZ+fxHOL9qzVU9gtANMrDKVEBVKYoZs1S3J3pWttL+2tZvdQ+tmIz2Kn+peLsnJcXfoFB1psDcfwMkvgO9Ae9QB9Bx9Pu-3h-PkHjvF86lwADVJdvQuZwNQALZuW3tkUKgIOSUPkqiPvYyiJB+36QOkXAgKAABUiHgAA8oIOLIX8ggoKA6BqNKqCQF+SToJgNgMKAADuKB9gAkkk9D0JRuBIEYiAoBg2AuFkACCtjwC+qBvtBP5mv+VaJGKJioPQn5iX+wpVl2Sa9vCyjGKYEFQSI8mQFJMlyTBoy2lubjrEBcKhNYtjaaAon6eKhl6YkADeAC+owxhk8FgBENB0IwrgcJw8x0Fge4BG4EyqpQZoxb2KyuaA7lcGF2CRdFPZDq5XCgKAagaPYfwJRED5FZ4GT5ZpsnFd2kwRNJWmVXlSS2Z4JXZZQ-F2C1nCpZwMDoMEZDpRFhJZQ1lDlZomy5Zw+WCKIuB-PN+X5QhhVkK4rX5UY9B-BJRCOKACF0QAIgAhLteFqOgh1Kcdp1gGIj3XQtKUZANY2ZfVsUUE1tVza1S00qtN0ITVjBYKQsBYH2O0fXtB1to9J1nVdN34fg92ox26MvW9rXuV9aUUOFv2ld17VXGt9nLeDSO3TjjPretCE2EQIVs9VRioOFD3489oCvR271syTxOk5wvmgHR5MZRNPG8Kh6C4EY+AUIooDJQEhIoKsfzSuoRHJClXBkxTE2gL4sBEe+WSKR2BmmOJj2jHTMPwPgqAAG6QAAFFtfwzUJIkiKKnPwH8PWCa+kAO5gLuyakACURsm5AyTS8rbi20RYqwBQASJ7+c4tEdyeME7AEKK1QePiHj5hwn5iRwJMcCS3pdV2nYyjMbPtZxQPmcAh+eiFwASoMmiAAELJpAE+l27ztOa7NfKaARhfugRE-uTiDL+Yvc661QRa1uRLBAH+FGL7tBuDj6ua9HoCqy-WuJHfD90EeRcBBDnbSAhdi493XinVOOsBqtS9j7f2DcNBNw0N3NuiQo6dy5qgkQvcoF0w2mAc6hAaSwAMF0KiRhWJMFws-DWWsboXxpAVUQdsyBKFYuxAAdAYABiDcDoIEqnG6MNcBwz7F7VhxMuAwM4NPWeoBeKlGPo7cuiBK4QOrqovGAEd572IpQXAR9gHgMBvQD259X5XwIFgW+dJf5uCwMAt+yik4aNSP0IYeDzYyw+nAv2gdg422bvHUu7cuaYLjsJVuOC3F4OEbDeG1CuGOKItzHmnCvxSCDv3AqnC-EIK2gIrmqchFM3ynkhgsAooBwDoSAIiQH6oCgQoUYdTQAADJ2mgEaaU-KA0ZEIQTGgTAOAp6WIKsAhUAdaGv0Nu-NWdD4DNNSK1Fem8iBV1XiKAOPDi5AILgAkxhk077Oia40xSpzFMxmVrBUNzEC6H0B5Kq60RFiNAFQKioAF4HhcY5C50yFmv0SLsgIqcXmSx8YwsgyRGBKDWVo9RpitnKQDpw9FKTRCnKOaYdxnjsUnzcTkz2CS+yfIUUo4BQcnGlIGWAAACgRfeFtZHjJIFQOkAQJ4KkxQHVOoRgToJSKkGphS2rFOJcw0RiSzInXcqUsZl9QBfmYAveg3KlC8v5coVCrFsDmEgioXVKAsCmOUCKvhRSlnEtgaSpgjjbzSIVaypVKqJ7YuUKDXAhrlDY3QOahUsKA6wKpanUVj4rXLLPkzN5iSbzE1TvEVq7LsBGC5cApNH0VVqu5QhQQCY6JiBFgmVCABVAAMudb5OIFHgFxL4XwqFfBcFKUAA). Also I reworked the issue so that all information is inside the issue for posterity. I also found that the reason `never` cannot be used is because of the `ArgsValue` type.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1:**

I found a workaround, though it requires a change in the interface:

```js
export interface FullRule<
  Type extends string,
  Field extends string
> {
  resolve(
    root: RootValue<Type>,
    args: ArgsValue<Type, Field>,
  ): boolean;
}

export interface PartialRule<Type extends string>
  extends FullRule<Type, any> {}

export interface GenericRule extends FullRule<any, any> {}

export type Rule<Type extends string, Field extends string> =
  | FullRule<TypeName, FieldName>
  | PartialRule<TypeName>
  | GenericRule;
```

With `and` becoming:

```js
export const and = <Type extends string, Field extends string>(
  ...rules: Rule<Type, Field>[]
): FullRule<Type, Field> => {
  return new RuleAnd<Type, Field>(rules);
};
```

The `and` returns a properly typed `FullRule<'MyType','MyField'>` and will thus reject the `badRule`. But it does require that I add new methods to create partial and generic rules.

Comment: Please consider turning the example code into a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to demonstrate what you're seeing.  Or maybe add a link to an existing web IDE that has the library dependencies already taken care of?

Comment: It is somewhat hard to show in codesanbox honestly I really tried, the best would be to run my example here: https://github.com/Sytten/nexus-shield/tree/master/examples/simple

Comment: I don't know that you can expect others to install projects on their local system; I personally am unlikely to do this.

Comment: @jcalz I created a playground with a simplified version of the problem (see the edit in the post). Sorry for being an asshole in my previous response. I would really appreciate if you can take a look!

Comment: Please provide all information directly here, not via extrnal links.

Comment: For that example, since your generics are in contravariant position, I'd try using `never` instead of `any` and seeing if that works.  If not, please elaborate on the issue.

Comment: If that doesn't work I'd look into making `genericRule` actually *generic* in the TS sense.  Will circle back later

Comment: Agreed never would work in this example, but in my real code it says type "MyType" is not assignable to type never. So I will rework my example. @Yunnosch all information is provided in the issue, not sure what you mean.

Comment: @jcalz Ok my new example is showing exactly what is wrong. It has to do with the ArgsValue type.

Comment: Blecch, those nexus helpers is a lot of conditional typing to wade through.  The problem I'm seeing is that the compiler does not accept that `Rule<A, B>` is contravariant in `A` and `B`, even though I think it should be.  Most of the "nice" solutions would involve using `Rule<string, string>` for the generic rules, and `and()` would naturally only accept the right types.  But that's not happening, likely because of the stuff in those helpers.  Hard to see how to fix it without throwing that stuff away. 

Comment: It just happens [naturally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBASgrgGwgHgCoBooFUB8UC8UAFAB4BcUGUIFWAlAXgEYD2LSAhgHYDcAsAChBAYxZcAzsCgBzCFwgAnAJbD4SCmpSTlXaZm1LdeQqUwgG+PMAVwIIsZKgALCAgQtNGxCgBELtyw+mD7ALgoQPsbEJGYWeABmHAjidkICohJS3AAmBFBomLhEAHSlHF5IBdg4ANoAunHRFFQ02I0cxRAAboogRMKMUMKm1HR0-GkZjiwA1hwgeTnIfq7uQVAhYRE4RLLyyqremP7umuNQAPQXULPz9plQTBy5hEs+0mzZTCARwVuRuzkihUmmOqw83nOVygigULAUAEJBFBBEA) if `Rule<A, B>` is considered contravariant in `A` and `B`.

Comment: Those nexus helpers are indeed quite complex and I don't have a lot of control over them since they are part of the framework (the source version is easier to read, I posted the link in the issue) :( 
I sent the issue to the devs to see if they have time to take a look and maybe they can make improvements to the helpers to help the compiler.
Otherwise the workaround 1 of using a union "works" since the compiler seems confused and just ignores the `any` (not sure it will hold long term though).

Comment: @jcalz I think I managed to get the contravariance working again? The issue lies in the last protection `? K3 extends keyof GenTypes[K][K2]`. I have no idea why though. If you remove it (and the corresponding `any`), it does no complain about `string` or `never` not being assignable to type `"Test"`. Though it is still not perfect because `and` becomes a `Rule<string, string>`  and accepts a bad rule (it does work correctly with `never` though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jcalz I was able to understand a few more things about the typing system of Typescript and basically realize even if I was able to make the contravariance work with the complex helpers of nexus, it would not achieve what I wanted to do.

So I took another approach instead. It is not perfect but works well enough. I defined two new operators:

```js
export const generic = (rule: Rule<any, any>) => <
  Type extends string,
  Field extends string
>(): Rule<Type, Field> => rule;

export const partial = <Type extends string>(rule: Rule<Type, any>) => <
  T extends Type, // NOTE: It would be best to do something with this type
  Field extends string
>(): Rule<Type, Field> => rule;
```

With those, the returned type becomes a generic function. When you call the function in the "typed context", it will prevent the propagation of `any`.

```js
const genericRule = generic(rule()((root, args) => { return true; }))

const myBadRule = rule()<"OtherType", "OtherField">((root, args) => {
  return true;
})

const myRule: Rule<"Test", "prop"> = and(
  rule()((root, args) => {
    return false
  }),
  genericRule(), //  Returns a Rule<"Test", "prop">
  myBadRule // ERROR
)
```

It is not perfect in the sense that mixing partial and generic rules is quite verbose and the type needs to be specified in the parent helper:

```js
const myPartialType = partial<'Test'>(
  rule()((root, _args, ctx) => {
    return true;
  })
);

const myCombination = partial<'Test'>(
  chain(
    isAuthenticated(),
    myPartialType()
  )
);
```

I still feel like this is somewhat of a hack, so I am still open to suggestions and better solution.